# Variable substitution in Universal Quantifier

Tags: logic, universal-property

During my math studies , I encountered variable substitutions as shown in the following examples:

$ \forall \epsilon>0 \, \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \, \forall n \in N . | a_n - L | < \epsilon $

$ \forall \epsilon>0 \, \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \, \forall n \in N . | a_n - L | < \frac{\epsilon}{4} $

Another example:

$  \forall n\in \mathbb{N} \, \exists s \in \mathbb{R} .n \leq s $

$  \forall n\in \mathbb{N} \, \exists s \in \mathbb{R} .n+2 \leq s $

$  \forall n\in \mathbb{N} \, \exists s \in \mathbb{R} .n+4 \leq s $

---

1. How do we go from $ \forall \epsilon>0 \, \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \, \forall n \in N . | a_n - L | < \epsilon $
   to:
   $ \forall \epsilon>0 \, \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \, \forall n \in N . | a_n - L | < \frac{\epsilon}{4} $
   ?

My naive thought was just to change the bound variable $ \epsilon $ to $ \frac{\epsilon}{4} $ so as to have:

$ \forall \frac{\epsilon}{4}>0 \, \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \, \forall n \in N . | a_n - L | < \frac{\epsilon}{4} $

But clearly this is incorrect since $ \frac{\epsilon}{4} $ is just a symbol and the 4 in the denominator is just part of the symbol and not really a number.

2. How do we go from  $  \forall n\in \mathbb{N} \, \exists s \in \mathbb{R} .n \leq s $

to:
$  \forall n\in \mathbb{N} \, \exists s \in \mathbb{R} .n+2 \leq s $?

Can you please give a rigorous explanation? ( I understand the intuition behind these representations, but I can't really concisely explain and/or write on a paper how do we go from one representation to another of these logical statements. )

Comment: For (1), for example, think of it as $\forall\epsilon > 0.\,P(\epsilon)$, where $P(\epsilon)$ is the statement $\exists N \in \mathbb N\,\forall n \in \mathbb N.\,\lvert a_n - L\rvert < \epsilon$.  Since $P(\epsilon)$ holds for *all* $\epsilon > 0$, in particular, for all $\epsilon > 0$, we have $\epsilon/4 > 0$ and so $P(\epsilon/4)$ holds; and that is your second statement, $\forall\epsilon > 0.\,P(\epsilon/4)$.  You can play a similar trick with $\forall n \in \mathbb N.\,Q(n + 2)$ or $\forall n \in \mathbb N.\,Q(n + 4)$.

Comment: @Lspice , does the following describe what you said for (1)?: $ \forall \epsilon \, . \epsilon>0 \rightarrow (\frac{\epsilon}{4}>0 \, \rightarrow P(\frac{\epsilon}{4}) ) $

This is equivalent to: 

$ \forall \epsilon \, . \epsilon>0 \land \frac{\epsilon}{4}>0 \rightarrow P(\frac{\epsilon}{4})  $

This is equivalent to: 

$ \forall \epsilon \, . \frac{\epsilon}{4}>0 \rightarrow P(\frac{\epsilon}{4})  $

Comment: I'm not sure any of [those](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/8172222) describes what I said, but they're all true; and, since $\epsilon > 0$ is equivalent to $\epsilon/4 > 0$, we have that $\forall\epsilon.\,\epsilon > 0 \land \epsilon/4 > 0 \implies P(\epsilon/4)$ is the same as $\forall\epsilon.\,\epsilon > 0 \implies P(\epsilon/4)$ and hence as $\forall\epsilon > 0.\,P(\epsilon/4)$, which is the claim you were trying to justify.  My claim was more like [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/8172509)

Comment: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/8172507) $(\forall\epsilon > 0.\,\epsilon/4 > 0) \land (\forall\epsilon > 0.\,(\epsilon/4 > 0 \implies P(\epsilon/4))$, from which we deduce $\forall\epsilon > 0.\,P(\epsilon/4)$.  If you want it all in one big symbolic formula, $((\forall\epsilon > 0.\,\epsilon/4 > 0) \land (\forall\epsilon > 0.\,(\epsilon/4 > 0 \implies P(\epsilon/4))) \implies (\forall\epsilon > 0.\,P(\epsilon/4))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of how you would prove that universal statement $ \forall \epsilon>0 \, \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \, \forall n \in N . | a_n - L | < \frac{\epsilon}{4} $. You would let $\epsilon$ be any real number greater than $0$, and you would have to show that for such an $\epsilon$, we have that $\exists N\in \mathbb{N} \, \forall n \in N . | a_n - L | < \frac{\epsilon}{4} $

OK, but why would the latter be true? It is because if $\epsilon > 0$, then we also have that $\frac{\epsilon}{4} > 0$, and we *already* know that for any real number (let's call it $\gamma$) it is true that $ \forall \gamma>0 \, \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \, \forall n \in N . | a_n - L | < \gamma $. Why do we know that? Because we were given that $ \forall \epsilon>0 \, \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \, \forall n \in N . | a_n - L | < \epsilon $, but the $\epsilon$ is just a 'dummy' variable, i.e. we can use any other variable ... in this case $\gamma$.

So, since that is true for any $\gamma > 0$ that $ \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \, \forall n \in N . | a_n - L | < \gamma $, the latter is specifically true for $\gamma = \frac{\epsilon}{4}$, and thus we know that for any $\epsilon > 0$ it is true that $\exists N\in \mathbb{N} \, \forall n \in N . | a_n - L | < \frac{\epsilon}{4} $.

In other words:  $ \forall \epsilon>0 \, \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \, \forall n \in N . | a_n - L | < \frac{\epsilon}{4} $.